# TransactionError: Transaction has been aborted. at Transaction._rollback

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to rollback a failed transaction, but it throws a TransactionError

I have tried capturing the exception why it failed but it only shows the error.

I am trying to insert a string in an int field which is causing the exception.

```
async create(tenantid: string, staff: StaffDto): Promise < any > {
  const connection = getConnection();
  const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
  await queryRunner.connect();
  await queryRunner.startTransaction();

  try {
    const userQuery = `insert into Users(Username, Password)  Output Inserted.Id values('${User.Username}', '${User.Password)
  }')`;
    await queryRunner.query(userQuery);

  const query = `insert into Address(CountryId,StateProvinceId,City,Address1,Address2,ZipPostalCode,PhoneNumber )  Output Inserted.Id values('${staff.Address.CountryId}','${staff.Address.StateProvinceId}','${staff.Address.City}','${staff.Address.Address1}','${staff.Address.Address2}','${staff.Address.ZipPostalCode}','${staff.Address.PhoneNumber}')`;
  await queryRunner.query(query);

  await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  return {
    ...staff,
    Id: userQueryResult[0].Id,
  };
} catch (err) {
  await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
  this.errorService.throwAPIError(err);

} finally {
  await queryRunner.release();
}
}
```

```
TransactionError: Transaction has been aborted.
    at Transaction._rollback (/Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/node_modules/mssql/lib/base.js:984:37)
    at Transaction._rollback (/Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:370:11)
    at Transaction.rollback (/Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/node_modules/mssql/lib/base.js:957:12)
    at /Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/src/driver/sqlserver/SqlServerQueryRunner.ts:156:37
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at SqlServerQueryRunner.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/src/driver/sqlserver/SqlServerQueryRunner.ts:155:16)
    at step (/Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:57)
    at /Users/xxx/Documents/codes/yyy/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Please write error capture code before rollback transaction. So, you will get sql error details. Same like `TRY CATCH` block in SQL Server. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-using-trycatch-in-a-transaction) for more details.

Comment: Catching the error from the sql query is fine but the problem is with rollback. It is throwing error on rollback. I want to know why cant it rollback. Even I tried to catch the rollbsck error but the same result as above is shown. No more details are given. When the second query fails, first succesful query is not rolling back its change.

Answer (score 0):

What does `this.errorService.throwAPIError(err);` do?  It might be console logging the `TransactionError`, but I don't think that an actual exception is being un-caught here.

A quick test would be to remove `this.errorService.throwAPIError(err);` and see if you still get the message in your console.

Comment: It does not even reach my custom exception handler. The execution stops at await.queryrunner.rollbacktransaction().